# Dynamicaly change class name of same class by adding number

Tags: javascript, classname

One final problem..how to dynamicaly change class name of same instruments by adding number?

```
<div class="score">
  <div class="system">
    <div class="stff_Flute"></div>
    <div class="stff_Flute"></div>
    <div class="stff_Clarinet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="system">
    <div class="stff_Flute"></div>
    <div class="stff_Flute"></div>
    <div class="stff_Clarinet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To this?...

```
<div class="score">
  <div class="system">
    <div class="stff_Flute_1"></div>
    <div class="stff_Flute_2"></div>
    <div class="stff_Clarinet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="system">
    <div class="stff_Flute_1"></div>
    <div class="stff_Flute_2"></div>
    <div class="stff_Clarinet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this code https://jsfiddle.net/7cLoxn29/1/ but something is wrong...

Comment: I think it could be relevant to add your code to your question

Comment: Whats wrong with your fiddle? Just because the text displayed says one thing, doesn't mean the class is the same

Comment: I don't think you should add index suffixes to your classes, it would be better to add a separate property for the index something like `data-index='1'` and so on

Comment: The classes aren't the same in the fiddle as the desired output, though they are indeed not representative of the text.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing for each ".system" element, you should loop over them and do that thing inside that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not terribly fond of jQuery, so I created a vanilla JS solution for you (hopefully that's OK!):

```
let parents = document.querySelectorAll(".system")
parents.forEach((parent) => {
  let children = parent.querySelectorAll("div")
  children = Array.from(children).reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    if (current.className in accumulator) {
      accumulator[current.className].push(current)
    } else {
      accumulator[current.className] = [current]
    }
    return accumulator
  }, {})

  for (var key in children) {
    if (children[key].length > 1) {
      children[key].forEach((child, i, target) => {
        child.className = `${child.className}_${i+1}`
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Note that this is ES2015 JS code.

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7cLoxn29/5/

Comment: Thank you, but unfortenately it is not always about Flute. I need this function to be universal for all instruments.

Comment: I see, I'm going to revise my answer then. Give me a few minutes! :)

Comment: @DominikSvoboda There, I've updated the answer which should work as intended. Ended up being quite the loop. If you need a more advanced version than this I think it's time to start looking into regex. I also added a link to a fiddle you can work with to check if it works as intended.

Comment: @DominikSvoboda I just fixed some minor issues after I re-read your question.

Comment: Nice...Thank you very very much.